# Why/when do moderators "force-migrate" a question that is on topic on two sites?

Tags: discussion, migration, moderation

This question got moved from SO to DBA by a moderator:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705916/sql-server-2008-how-do-i-change-the-default-schema-of-the-dbo?noredirect=1

The question is about why an ALTER USER statement fails in certain conditions.  That seems easily on-topic for both SO and DBA.

Why did a moderator "force-migrate" this specific question, bypassing the normal requirement of five votes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, there's not a migration path from Stack Overflow to DBA so if a migration was necessary it would *have* to be by moderator action.

I'm not a moderator on SO, but I assume that there were flags on the question suggesting that it would get better answers on DBA - moderators don't have the time to go looking for questions to migrate (especially on SO) so would only react to a flag. If that's the case then the moderator obviously agreed and migrated the question.

This could also be true of Wordpress plugin development questions or Game Development questions. Both these areas are on topic for Stack Overflow, but as dedicated sites exist for these areas questions could, and should, be migrated if they will get better answers on the other site.

Comment: Last sentence is key. Will it get a better answer on the other site? Our objective is to get the best answers to the questions. If it's best on the site it's on, it should stay. Usually, it's better on the appropriate 'focused' site. I fear, though, that people feel moderator action is a sign of disapproval or some other negative connotation. In this sense, it couldn't be further from the truth!